# Python Skipping my for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

First off note that I am a beginner in Python. Taking a class currently dealing with Python in an ArcGIS environment. My current project is a simple program to create files and copy other files to them. However part of the assignment is to have print statements state what is going on as it happens, for instance the final print statement should look like:

Processing Polygon FeatureClasses....

Processing FeatureClass >> Building

Field Information:

```
 etc.
```

Here is the small bit of my code that should do that:

```
pointlist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "Point")
print "Processing Point FeatureClasses..."
for pl in pointlist:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(pl, "Point" + 1)
    pointlayer = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(pl, "intersect", MapGridID)
    pointcount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(pointlayer).getOutput(0))
    if pointcount >= 1:
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pointlayer, OutputGDB)
    for pl in pointlist:
        print "Processing FeatureClass:" + pl
        pointfield = arcpy.ListFields()
        for pf in pointfield:
            print "Field Name:" + pf
```

The issue arises that it prints the first print statement, "Processing Point FeatureClasses" but doesn't do the rest and then skips to my next part of the code and executes that. Any idea why? Sorry if my formatting or wording is off/sounds weird. Thank you.

*EDIT*

I emailed my professor as well asking for some guidance and he wrote back a slightly edited version of my above code block. I can now get everything to print out except the pointfield print statements, those are now getting skipped. Here is the code:

```
pointlist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "Point")
print "Processing Point FeatureClasses...\n"
i = 1
for pl in pointlist:
    print "Processing FeatureClass: " + pl
    featlayernamepoint = "Point" + str(i)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(pl, featlayernamepoint)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(featlayernamepoint, "intersect",   featurelayerMG2)
    pointcount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(featlayernamepoint).getOutput(0))
    if pointcount >= 1:
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featlayernamepoint, OutputGDB)
        pointfield = arcpy.ListFields(featlayernamepoint)
        for pf in pointfield:
            print "Field Name: " + pf.name
    i += 1
```

Comment: Apparently, `pointlist` is empty. Try printing it to be sure: `print(pointlist)`, just before the loop.

Comment: What does `print pointlist` yield? By the looks of things it's empty.

Comment: One of my issues was the pointlist was empty. That was an easy fix of me not specifying my workspace pathname correctly

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass the point to ListFields()

```
pointfield = arcpy.ListFields(pl)
for pf in pointfield:
      print "Field Name:" + pf.name
```

Comment: That was another issue in my code that my professor pointed out to me just now.